# Why do some COM indexes start at 1 instead of 0?

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, com

I'm using COM to interact with Excel, and was surprised to find that a 2D array started with an index of `[1,1]` instead of `[0,0]`. This is super confusing since, as far as I'm aware, all other array indexes in the world ever would have started with an index of `[0,0]`.

This gets even more confusing when, on this [1,1] starting array, methods such as `getLength()` still use a starting index of `0` when operating on the array.

Questions:

1. What is the reason that COM 2D arrays start at 1?
2. Is this standard across all COM arrays? (I guess this could be an attempt to specifically map arrays to Excel's `R1C1` referencing style)

This is the code that produces the COM array with offensive indexes:

```
// Open the worksheet (just for background)
Excel.Application app = (Excel.Application)ExcelDnaUtil.Application;
Excel.Workbook wb = app.ActiveWorkbook;
Excel.Worksheet _DB_SCRAPE = wb.Worksheets["_DB_SCRAPE"];

// Get the contents of the worksheet (THIS LINE OF CODE)
object[,] contents = _DB_SCRAPE.Range[_DB_SCRAPE.Cells[rowFirst,colFirst],_DB_SCRAPE.Cells[rowLast,colLast]].Value2;
```

The `contents` object has indexes that start at `[1,1]`.

Comment: It's a sad story.  In the early days of OLE, collection indexes were always 1-based, because it's more intuitive, right?  Then ADO came along with 0-based collection indexes.  So now we have the situation where some collection indexes are 1-based and others are 0-based, and in most cases the documentation doesn't tell you which - you have to work it out for yourself by guesswork, google or trial and error.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with COM.  This decision goes all the way back to 1991, Basic was the client programming language target for Office, starting with Excel.  And Basic back then had a heavy preference for starting array indices at 1.  Joel Spolsky. the CEO of SO was heavily involved btw, he wrote about the experience [here](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2006/06/16/my-first-billg-review/).

Comment: @HansPassant. that article mentions a tradeoff of memory where 1900 was treated as if it were not a leapyear, even though it was so as to allow easier checking for future leap years? Interesting, but I don't see how that relates to indexes starting at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: oh wow this is surprising: https://www.quora.com/Why-is-it-that-1896-was-a-leap-year-but-not-1900